# SQL Query to find only unique strings from 2 columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table with 2 columns, both having names

I want a query that finds only unique names - names that only appear once max in the entire table.

For example, for the following table:

```
NAME1    |     NAME2
--------------------
DAN             MIKE
MIKE            TONY
FOO              DAN
```

It should only return FOO and TONY.

Thanks

Comment: Could `NAME1` or `NAME2` be null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could do it a few ways, but here's one (assuming Name1 and Name2 are of the same, or implicitly convertible types):

```
SELECT [Name]
FROM (SELECT Name1 AS [Name] FROM [Table] UNION ALL SELECT Name2 FROM [Table])
GROUP BY [Name]
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the simple:

```
select name1 from table where name1 not in (select distinct name2 from table ) 
union 
select name2 from table where name2 not in (select distinct name1 from table );
```

Comment: This will not work if there are 2 records with the same `name1` or `name`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `name1` and `name2` cannot be null, use this query:

```
SELECT t.Name1
FROM tableName t LEFT JOIN tableName t2 ON t.NAME1 = t2.NAME2
WHERE t2.NAME2 IS NULL
GROUP BY t.Name1
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT t.Name2
FROM tableName t LEFT JOIN tableName t2 ON t.NAME2 = t2.NAME1
WHERE t2.NAME1 IS NULL
GROUP BY t.Name2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

If they can be null, use this query:

```
SELECT Name
FROM (
  SELECT t.Name1 Name
  FROM tableName
  GROUP BY t.Name1
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.Name2 Name
  FROM tableName
  GROUP BY t.Name2
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) rs
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

@CheeseConQueso interpreted the question differently than I did. I thought you meant unique names from *both* columns combined.

Here's my version:

```
select name, count(*) from (select name1 as name from table union select name2 as name from table) group by name having count(*) = 1;
```

You can wrap the whole thing in a "select name from ..." to get the names alone, or this could be rewritten using an analytic function instead of grouping to filter the duplicates. Depends on the capabilities of your database.

Comment: And that's because...UNION removes duplicates, which would affect the count; UNION ALL leaves duplicates intact. I learned something new :-).